# Error loading YUMI on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: dual-boot, yumi

I installed yumi on ubuntu 13.04.When i run YUMI,it shows the following error.

```
Drive /dev/sdb1(New\\x20vo) is not mounted in /media.
please mount usb via file manager and restart YUMI.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with YUMI on openSUSE. It's a bug in YUMI. Workaround is to remount drive (as a root, use `sudo` or `su`) to /media subfolder as YUMI expects:

```bash
umount /dev/sdb1
mkdir /media/usbdisk
mount /dev/sdb1 /media/usbdisk
```

And then launch YUMI again.

Read about GNU/Linux command `mount` for more details.

Comment: Just encountered this myself today.  rominf's answer (which helped me out) but root cause of the bug seems to be that YUMI for Linux (at least the Ubuntu package) doesn't like volume labels that have spaces in them. It would appear Avinash's USB drive had a derivative of the default Windows provided name "New volume". Use one of the various disk tools available to remove spaces from the label. "Edit Filesystem" on the partition in Disks, "Label" on the partition in GParted, etc.